# Trying to do an output while a choice from each listbox is selected

Tags: c#, listboxitem

I am trying to do 1 of 3 options when selecting from 2 different listboxes with the same measurement words.

The user enters a number into a textbox, then selects one of 3 units in the FromList listbox (the units are Inches, Feet, and Yards), then selects one of 3 units in the ToList listbox (the units in this are also Inches, Feet, and Yards).

When the calculate button is clicked it will either convert the measurement inches to inches (Do no math and just spit out what they entered to the label) or inches to feet or inches to yards if the FromList has Inches selected, and display the output to a label. It would also do feet to inches, feet to feet(do no math), and feet to yards. Lastly, it would do yards to inches, yards to feet, and yards to yards (do no math).

Both listboxes have SelectionMode set to One so user can only pick 1 item from each listbox. I can set the first listbox to a value with SelectedItem, but the 9 errors in the code it is highlighting is if I try to set it if an item in the 2nd listbox is selected.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    public frmConverter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtEntered.Text = "";
        lblOutput.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Fromlist;
        string ToList;
        double Entered, Output;

        Entered = Convert.ToDouble(txtEntered.Text);

        if (FromList == "Inches" && ToList == "Inches")
        {
            lblOutput.Text = txtEntered.Text + " Inches";
        }
        else if (FromList == "Inches" && ToList =="Feet")
        {
            Output = Entered / 12;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Feet");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Inches" && ToList == "Yards")
        {
            Output = Entered / 36;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Yards");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Feet" && ToList == "Inches")
        {
            Output = Entered * 12;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Inches");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Feet" && ToList == "Feet")
        {
            lblOutput.Text = txtEntered.Text + " Feet";
        }
        else if (FromList == "Feet" && ToList == "Yards")
        {
            Output = Entered / 3;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Yards");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Yards" && ToList == "Inches")
        {
            Output = Entered * 36;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Inches");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Yards" && ToList == "Feet")
        {
            Output = Entered * 12;
            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + (" Feet");
        }
        else if (FromList == "Yards" && ToList == "Yards")
        {
            lblOutput.Text = txtEntered + " Yards";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the details of the errors you are getting?

Comment: yes the error is   :  'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) it has SelectedItem underlined after each part of ToList.SelectedItem = for all 9 of the ToList

Comment: Is it because you're declaring `string Fromlist`? I notice that the casing is different in your code (`Fromlist` is never used).

Comment: tried clearing all variables that were strings used Tinstaafl response and now it's spitting out the same original 9 plus 9 more of  " Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' and 'string' "  Entered is what they enter in the textbox and it is a double

Comment: tried removing strings as jadavparesh mentioned, but still getting the same errors with 9 additional : Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'object'  errors

Comment: trying tinstaafls suggestion again

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is you're using the assignment operator,`=`, instead of the equality operator,`==`, in your if statements.

```
if (FromList.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Inches" && ToList.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Inches")
{
    lblOutput.Text = txtEntered.Text + " Inches";
}
```

Also `Entered` is never given a value.

Something you might want to consider, is using an enum to simplify your code and get rid of all those `if` statements:

```
    enum Conversions
    {
        Inches = 1,
        Feet = 12,
        Yards = 36,
    }
    double DoConversion(string from, string to, double quantity)
    {
        Conversions convertFrom = Conversions.Inches;
        Conversions convertTo = Conversions.Inches;
        if (Enum.TryParse<Conversions>(from, out convertFrom) && Enum.TryParse<Conversions>(to, out convertTo))
        {
            return quantity * ((double)convertFrom / (double)convertTo);
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

This function takes the From/To units as strings and a double for the quantity and does the conversion.  Instead of different algorithms for multiplying or dividing, it just multiplies by the division of the 2 conversion values

Comment: It's now down to 4 errors

Use of unassigned local variable 'ToList'

Use of unassigned local variable 'FromList'

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' and 'string' 

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' and 'string'

Comment: @Drakkhul - You've got some confusion in your naming of your variables then.  If `FromList` and `ToList` are listboxes, you shouldn't be naming the strings `Tolist` and `Fromlist`, it makes it hard to distinguish between them. I edited my answer to use listboxes.

Comment: I'm in a beginning class and nowhere near using enum anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have taken FromList and ToList as string and you are trying to polulate SelectedItem propert from FromList/ToList but there is no such property exists in FromList/ToList as you have taken them as string in your code. May be you required to use your Listcontrols defined in desigining rather than taking string objects in code.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Fromlist; // this is string so will not work for you
        string ToList;  // this is string so will not work for you
        string Inches;
        string Feet;
        string Yards;
        double Entered, Output;
//as FromList and ToList are string defined above below logic will not work as there is no property like SelectedItem in string.
 if (FromList.SelectedItem = "Inches" && ToList.SelectedItem = "Inches")
        {
}
```

Comment: It's now down to 4 errors

Use of unassigned local variable 'ToList'

Use of unassigned local variable 'FromList'

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' and 'string' 

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' and 'string'

Comment: Can you please tell me how your FromList and ToList Listboxes display in UI?

Comment: FromList is on the left and has 3 choices in it listed top to bottom : Inches, Feet, Yards (each on their own line)   To list is to the right of it and also has the same choices listed top to bottom : Inches, Feet, Yards (each on their own line)

Comment: I recoded the entire thing with the exact code listed above just to make sure there are no typos and it is down to 2 errors              Use of unassigned local variable 'ToList' Use of unassigned local variable 'FromList'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I recoded it using switch and parse and it works as intended now. Thanks for everyone's help!Here is the working code :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtEntered.Text = "";
        lblOutput.Text = "";
    }
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string From;
        string To;
        double Entered, Output;

        Entered = double.Parse(txtEntered.Text);

        if (FromList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            From = FromList.SelectedItem.ToString();
            To = ToList.SelectedItem.ToString();
            switch (From)
            {
                case "Inches":
                    switch (To)
                    {
                        case "Inches":
                            Output = Entered;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Inches";
                            break;
                        case "Feet":
                            Output = Entered / 12;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Feet";
                            break;
                        case "Yards":
                            Output = Entered / 36;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Yards";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                    case "Feet":
                    switch (To)
                    {
                        case "Inches":
                            Output = Entered * 12;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Inches";
                            break;
                        case "Feet":
                            Output = Entered;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Feet";
                            break;
                        case "Yards":
                            Output = Entered / 3;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Yards";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                    case "Yards":
                    switch (To)
                    {
                        case "Inches":
                            Output = Entered * 36;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Inches";
                            break;
                        case "Feet":
                            Output = Entered * 3;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Feet";
                            break;
                        case "Yards":
                            Output = Entered;
                            lblOutput.Text = Output.ToString("N2") + " Yards";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        }
    }
}
```